# Check if element of object exists in request

Tags: php, object

if a $request object and I need check if some values are on $request

```
Request {#43 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#170 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#172 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:18 [▼
      "_token" => "sT4yCby4ieh3rHAK0MBcMIcYkGMDzjs0Jf1co4WS"
      "is_demand" => "1"
      "title" => null
      "main_category" => "C01"
      "secondary_category" => "C0201"
      "main_category_2" => "C01"
      "secondary_category_2" => "C0201"
      "status" => "granted"
      "interest" => "code1"
      "keywords" => null
      "keywords_secondary" => null
      "challenge" => null
      "requirement" => null
      "summary" => null
      "dateStart" => "1970-01-01"
      "dateEnd" => "2017-11-07"
      "trlMin" => null
      "trlMax" => null
    ]
  }
```

Try

```
if ( ! property_exists($this->request, 'is_demand')) {
   throw new \Exception('"is_demand" is undefined');
}
```

But get exception, although is_demand is defined and has value

What is my error or my lack of understanding?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->request` is a [`ParameterBag`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html). Not only that it doesn't have the `is_demand` property but you don't even care about its properties but about the values of the parameters it contains.

Use the [`has()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_has) method provided by the [`ParameterBag`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html) class to find out what you need:

```
if ($this->request->has('is_demand')) {
    $is_demand = $this->request->get('is_demand');
}
```